# CQL: Select all rows, distinct partition key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3, phantom-dsl

I have a table

```
    CREATE TABLE userssbyprofit (
    userid text,
    profit double,
    dateupdated timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, profit, dateupdated)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (profit DESC, dateupdated DESC)
```

Userid can be used to lookup the full user details in another table. This table will provide a history of the users profits. Taking the most recent one to find their current profit amount.

How do I retrieve the 10 most profitable users with their profit amount. I want it to be distinct based on the userID

Thanks.

Comment: Select Disctinct userid from userssbyprofit limit 10 ?

Comment: @Whitefret I want to get all columns not just userID, your solution would only give me userid

Comment: yeah, then with the userId you can make another query to have everything no?

Comment: @Whitefret Yeah that is an option. will they still be ordered by profit? thanks

Comment: I guess so, because it is your clustering key

Comment: @Whitefret Im getting ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN

Comment: true, then create another table like I said in the other post's comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create one more table or view which have only user id and profit . New table or view will have user id order by profit with desc order .

Comment: I now have a table userid text,
    profit double,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, profit)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (profit DESC) but this is returning the results in random order

Comment: If you don't mind creating a table, do it the other way around: Primary key (profit, userid)